# memcpy size value

Tags: c++, memory

I will copy the data I received with `recv()` and the maximum size is MAX_PACKET for in/out buffers.

Is it safe to copy it with the fixed size `MAX_PACKET`? Is it necessary for me to set the right size of the buffer when I use memcpy ?

```
recv(sock,recvbuf,MAX_PACKET,0);
memcpy(inbuffer,recvbuf,MAX_PACKET);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to declare inbuffer at least as many bytes as the size of MAX_PACKET
char * inbuffer = new char[MAX_PACKET];

and place before each recv()
memset(inbuffer,0,MAX_BUFFER);
to zero out the buffer so you don't mistakenly see the tail end of a previous packet in the scenario you received two packets where the 2nd is shorter than the 1st.

if your incoming packet has no unique termination byte ie '\r' 
you need to add
int recvbytes ;
recvbytes =new recv(...)
since recv returns the number of bytes received on the wire

Comment: so i will simply put a memcpy(inbuffer,recvbuffer,recvbytes) ?

Answer (score 0):

Safe yes but wasteful. Also don't forget to not use the data returned in inbuffer beyond the actual received data from recvbuf.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless inBuffer is at least as large as MAX_PACKET.

In addition to what Oezbek said, recv won't 0 terminate either unless it actually receives a 0.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative approach

```
 std::string inbuffer; // member variable to the class
 .......
 int ret = recv(sock,recvbuff,MAX_PACKET);
 if(ret != 0)
 {
   inbuffer.insert(inbuffer.end(),recvbuff, recvbuff + ret);

 ...... // use the data.
 }
```

this avoids using memcpy. Directly anyways, the STD lib should do the smart thing and call memcpy/ memmove for you :)

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `.end()` as the `result` of your `copy`?

Comment: @EugenConstantinDinca yes, it appends the data, it's the same as calling append on the string object, and the effects are the same. the first bit of the recv buffer becomes where the end is, and as the call to resize increases the available memory, so copy happily scribbles to the extra memory created by the call to reszie. and the entire character array of the packet transmission gets 'reassembled' into the string buffer with next to no overhead. it would be the same as using a standard char * , but with the added security of c++ containers.

Comment: @EugenConstantinDinca and the reason for appending this data is the exact same reason you gave in your answer Eugene, when receiving packets you may or may not get all of the packet with one call to recv.

Comment: I wasn't questioning the idea, I was questioning the implementation. `resize` moves `end()` so you're still going to dereference `end` (which yields undefined behaviour). You can use `back_inserter` (& not resize).

Comment: @EugenConstantinDinca oops . fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary for you to set the right size of the buffer when you use `memcpy` because `recv` will put in `recvbuf` only as much data as is currently available and up to your specified size of `MAX_PACKET`. Not even if on the other end you're doing `send(sock,sendbuf,MAX_PACKET,0);` (and `MAX_PACKET` has the same value in both places).
The only scenario in which your code would make sense would be if you're using UDP (`SOCK_DGRAM`) and all your datagrams are of size `MAX_PACKET`.